# Rxjava : Schedulers.io() vs Schedulers.from(scheduledExecutorService)

Tags: rx-java2, scheduledexecutorservice, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Rxjava2 with spring boot 2 and spring cloud finchley.

Now Issue i am facing is schedulers.io(), is not generating new trace ids, its reusing them from previous requests. I am assuming this must be because they are reused and thus they are using old data. Code is :

```
Observable<Optional<String>> data = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        Observable<Optional<String>> data1 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        Observable<Optional<String>> data2 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        Observable<Optional<String>> data3 = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

But I have changed my code. I created my own **ScheduledExecutorService**

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =  Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    Observable<Optional<String>> data = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(scheduler));
    Observable<Optional<String>> data1 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(scheduler));
    Observable<Optional<String>> data2 = client.getWorld1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(scheduler));
    Observable<Optional<String>> data3 = client.getWorld().subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(scheduler));
```

Now traceids are getting generated new every time?

Now my question is : 
a) Why does it starts working with ScheduledExecutorService. I mean since it is also a pool and it must also be using the thread pool and thus old threads.

b) How does ScheduledExecutorService actually works?

Comment: We don't really support RxJava2 out of the box. The suggested mechanism is to use Reactor (which I guess is not really comforting for you). Maybe you should wrap the `ScheduledExecutorService` in the `TraceableScheduledExecutorService` representation and the tracing context will be propagated properly?

Comment: You shouldn't be constructing multiple RxJava schedulers from the same executor service. Instead, create a single scheduler. Each use of `subscribeOn()` will put the observable on to an individual thread.

Comment: But I want to run all all calls in different thread?